# Htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to make www.purchase.domain.com redirect to purchase.domain.com, below is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.DOMAIN_NAME/$1 [L,R]
```

I need a variable that will replace DOMAIN_NAME with simply purchase.domain.com

Obviously i can hard code the purchase.domain.com but i will need the code to work on multiple sites. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a RewriteCond backreference.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.%1/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://purchase.%1/$1
```

Which suprisingly similar to the one posted while I was posting.