# Redirect absolutely anything to new domain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, zeus

Ok, so I'm in need a simple redirect:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com/
```

Similar to that, except I want it to catch anything, such as:

```
www.old.com/blah/blah/?xyz=123&aaaaabbbb=erewr3ttt#ewtjhirhjerh
```

and send the user to:

```
www.new.com
```

Should be easy right? Finding out how to do this is not so easy. Using the above rule we're still getting 404's for things that aren't there rather than the Redirect rule just getting everything.

Comment: Ever thought of `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess Redirect](http://serverfault.com/questions/49361/htaccess-redirect)

Comment: Skip the .htaccess and put it directly into your server configuration.  You may already have rewrite enabled or something.  Remove that from your configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the `RedirectMatch` directive instead of using mod_rewrite:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://www.new.com/
```

Note the `^` can be interchanged with `.*`, both regular expressions with match everything.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The `(.*)` will match everything, and redirect to just http://www.new.com/.

**Edit:** This was for Apache, I've retagged the question as being for Zeus.

Comment: Turns out it was Zeus Webserver so that didn't work (or rewriteengine doesn't exist/work on zeus..who knows.) :/ Nevermind.